# How to test complex functions in eXist-db with XQSuite

Tags: unit-testing, xquery, exist-db

I’d like to use tests for my app. I have checked the Documentation as well as the particular chapter in the book by A. Retter. However, I have no idea how to use another types of arguments (especially nodes). My functions are typically of a much higher level than those converting numbers or strings.

For example, I would like to test a function which takes a document (node) as its argument and returns a) an HTML file; b) a pdf file.

Testing function (here I try to test the first functionality mentioned above):

```
xquery version "3.0";

module namespace cust = 'http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/db/apps/karolinum-x/modules/cust';

declare namespace tei  = 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0';
declare namespace test = 'http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite';
declare
    %test:args('<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
                    <text>
                        <body>
                            <div n="1">
                                <head>Heading</head>
                                <p>paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </text>')
    %test:assertXPath('$result/html')
function cust:transform($doc as node()*) as node() {
    let $styles := doc('/db/apps/karolinum-x/resources/xslt/style-web.xsl')
    let $document := 
        (
            <book n='1'>{($doc//tei:div[@n='1'])[1]}</book>
        )
    let $finale := transform:transform($document, $styles, ())
    return $finale
};
```

Test runner:

```
xquery version "3.0";

import module namespace test = 'http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite' at 'resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/xqsuite/xqsuite.xql';

test:suite(inspect:module-functions(xs:anyURI('test-test.xqm')))
```

Result:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite package="http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/db/apps/karolinum-x/modules/cust" timestamp="2016-03-15T12:53:16.5+01:00" failures="0" pending="0" tests="1" time="PT0.002S">
        <testcase name="transform" class="cust:transform">
            <error type="err:XPTY0004" message="It is a type error if,
                during the static analysis phase, an expression is found to have a
                static type that is not appropriate for the context in which the
                expression occurs, or during the dynamic evaluation phase, the dynamic 
                type of a value does not match a required type as specified by the 
                matching rules in 2.5.4 SequenceType Matching."/>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so two things:

1. Your missing the closing `</TEI>` from your XML that you are injecting via the `%test:args` annotation.
2. You seem to have found a bug in XQSuite. I can confirm that using XML in your `%test:args` with a function argument that has either no explicit type or an explicit type of `node()` doesn't work. Can you please open an issue for this on https://github.com/exist-db/exist/issues. As a workaround if you change `$doc as node()*` to `$doc as element()*` then that does seem to work.

p.s. Your test seems a little brittle as you are hard-coding a path to a database document inside your tests, better to inject the path, or even better yet, to avoid side-effecting functions like doc() and collection() inside your function under test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints, it really helped! Of course, I will open the issue.

Comment: The only one problem remaining is I can't make the `assertXPath` to pass :) I would think `($result/html)` should work but it does not.

Comment: Wow, really can’t understand why the assert does not work. `$result//@*` works, `$result//*` works, `$result//*[@class = "chapter"]` works, `$result/html` **does not**. What am I missing here? It is not possible to grab any element here, even `$result//html` or `$result//body` **does not work**.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl This was not your original question. Can I suggest opening a new question on Stackoverflow... or better yet an issue on the eXist mailing list or bug tracker.

Comment: Yes, I know, I will open the new one, thank you a lot!